# Trouble with getaddrinfo(), on client side

Tags: c++, linux, connection

I am showing the code for Server and client. Platform is Linux (Fedora). The problem I am having is that, the client after a while times out on connect() call, and fails. However, the mystery is more what getaddrinfo() does. The address that it is using for connect() is different from the address that I passed to the structure hints. Why is that happening?

Why the program client fails to connect?

`Server.cpp`

```
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#include <sys/un.h>

#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " port-number" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else cout << "Server(), incoming port: " << argv[1] << endl;

    int sockDescriptor, reqSocket, childpid;

    struct addrinfo hints, *result, *p;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    char buf[126];
    if (gethostname(buf, sizeof(buf)) < 0){
        cout << "Server(), gethostname() failed." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else cout << "Server(), Hostname: " << buf << endl;

    if (getaddrinfo(buf, argv[1], &hints, &result) != 0) {
        cout << "Server(), getaddrinfo() failed" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    struct addrinfo sa, sa4;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    memset(&sa4, 0, sizeof(sa4));

    bool AllDone = false;

    for (p = result; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
            if (!AllDone) {
                memcpy(&sa, p, sizeof(sa));
                sockDescriptor = socket(sa.ai_family, sa.ai_socktype, sa.ai_protocol);
                if (sockDescriptor == -1) continue;
                if (bind(sockDescriptor, sa.ai_addr, sa.ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                    close(sockDescriptor);
                }
                else {
                    AllDone = true;
                    inet_ntop(sa.ai_family, &(sa.ai_addr), buf, 125);
                    cout << "Server(), Server Address: " << buf << endl;
                }
            } //endif AllDone
        }
        else if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            memcpy(&sa4, p, sizeof(sa4));
            inet_ntop(sa4.ai_family, &(sa4.ai_addr), buf, 125);
            cout << "Server(), Server Address: " << buf << endl;
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (!AllDone) {
        cout << "Server(), getaddrinfo() did not get address..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else cout << "Server(), getaddrinfo() succeeded..." << endl;

    if (listen(sockDescriptor, 5) == -1) {
        cout << "Server(), listen() failed" << endl;
        close(sockDescriptor);
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;) {
        if ((reqSocket = accept(sockDescriptor, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
            cout << "Server(), accept() failed, continuing" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        if ((childpid = fork()) < 0) {
            cout << "Server(), Could not fork for accept. Quitting" << endl;
            close(sockDescriptor);
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (!childpid) {
            cout << "Server(), accepted client request..." << endl;
            close(reqSocket);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`Client.cpp`

```
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#include <sys/un.h>

#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " host-address"  << " port-number" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Client(), incoming address: " << argv[1] << endl;
        cout << "Client(), incoming port: " << argv[2] << endl;
    }

    int sockDescriptor;
    struct addrinfo hints, *result, *p;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &result) != 0) {
        cout << "Client(), getaddrinfo() failed" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    struct addrinfo sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

    bool AllDone = false;

    for (p = result; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
            if (!AllDone) {
                memcpy(&sa, p, sizeof(sa));
                sockDescriptor = socket(sa.ai_family, sa.ai_socktype, sa.ai_protocol);
                if (sockDescriptor == -1) continue;
                if (connect(sockDescriptor, sa.ai_addr, sa.ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                    close(sockDescriptor);
                    char buf[126];
                    inet_ntop(sa.ai_family, &(sa.ai_addr), buf, 125);
                    cout << "Client(), connect() failed for address: " << buf << endl;
                }
                else {
                    AllDone = true;
                    break;
                }
            } //endif AllDone
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (!AllDone) {
        cerr << "Client(), getaddrinfo() did not get address..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Client(), connection to server succeeded." << endl;
        close(sockDescriptor);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inet_ntop` doesn't work with `struct sockaddr`. It needs an IP address, not a socket address. See https://gist.github.com/jkomyno/45bee6e79451453c7bbdc22d033a282e

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Now the mystery is gone. I get the same address for connect(). But it still does "connection time out", and fails.

Comment: Before te3sting your own client and server, make sure the standard ones work (use `nc` for example). You may have a network configuration problem. Also test on the loopback address.

Comment: Using ifconfig I noticed that getaddrinfo() is binding with an ipv6 indicated as <Link>. So, for the Server code I replaced the hostname with an ipv6 indicated as <Global>, and all worked fine. So, why is getaddrinfo() picking an address that does not allow connections? How can I tell it to choose a correct address when using hostname?

Comment: No idea but see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/242013/difference-between-link-local-and-global-link-addresses-in-isatap).

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. Now, for getaddrinfo() this is what is happening. I am just saying it perhaps someone might have an idea. According to documentation, if I set the flag to passive, and make node (where hostname goes) NULL, it should work. But what I get for address is all 0. I even tried examples given as answer here/there, still got all 0. But I need to see what address server is using so I can pass it to client. It has been a long night. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was finally solved as follows. Use hostname for node, do not use NULL. Discard addresses containing 0000. I will only show the main loop as modified for Server.

```
    struct addrinfo sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

    bool AllDone = false;

    for (p = result; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *psa = (struct sockaddr_in6*)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(psa->sin6_addr), buf, 125);

            if (strstr(buf, "::")) {
                cout << "Server(), Server ipv6 Address (skipped): " << buf << endl;
                continue;
            }

            if (!AllDone) {
                memcpy(&sa, p, sizeof(sa));
                sockDescriptor = socket(sa.ai_family, sa.ai_socktype, sa.ai_protocol);
                if (sockDescriptor == -1) continue;
                if (bind(sockDescriptor, sa.ai_addr, sa.ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                    close(sockDescriptor);
                }
                else {
                    AllDone = true;
                    cout << "Server(), bind() succeeded for address: " << buf << endl;
                }
            } //endif AllDone
        }
        else if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            struct sockaddr_in *psa = (struct sockaddr_in*)p->ai_addr;
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(psa->sin_addr), buf, 125);
            cout << "Server(), Server ipv4  Address: " << buf << endl;
        }
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
```